# Using PHP preg_match with parentheses ()

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I'm trying to write a regex to match a string which contains at most 2 numbers,and does not contain particular signs such as `%` or `=` for example:

```
my name is jojo -> catch all

my name is jojo i'm 20 years old -> catch all

my name is jojo i'm 20 years old and 6 miles away -> catch all

blablabla 40% my name is jojo -> should only catch "my name is jojo"
```

The fact is that i cant manage to use `|` combined with `()` in the regex expression:
i'm now trying to do something like this but it's not working... :

```
preg_match_all("/(([^0-9=%]|\r\n|\s){10,}[0-9,.]*){2}/",$string,$match);
```

Thank you in advance for your help. Johny

Comment: Because of the first part : ([^0-9=%]|\r\n|\s){10,} which requires at least 10 non numerical caracters neither spaces, i dont know if the synthax is good though

Comment: Leave regex syntax aside your requirements aren't very clear to me. I don't understand why `blablabla` shouldn't be matched but `name` is matched

Comment: its not "name" which is matched but "my name is jojo" which contains > 10 non numerical caracters. "blablabla" only contains 9 so it will not be matched

Comment: And why `blablabla 40` shouldn't be matched, it contains 12 characters and only 2 digits ?

Comment: Because it does not begin with at least 10 non numerical caracters or spaces

Comment: Yes, it does, 9 alpha + 1 space

Comment: 10 non (numerical caracters OR spaces) = 10 (non numerical caracters AND non spaces)

Comment: OK, but why `my name is jojo` should be matched, there are spaces, no?

Comment: @johny this question has stalled into abandonment.  Please help to keep SO clean and either edit your question to clarify your objective or delete your question.  As is, this question cannot by confidently answered and will not be very useful to future SO readers.

Answer (score 0):

> i'm now trying to do something like this but it's not working... :
>
> ```
> preg_match_all("/(([^0-9=%]|\r\n|\s){10,}[0-9,.]*){2}/",$string,$match);
> ```

You are not far from the solution. Compare:

```
$strings = array("my name is jojo",
                 "my name is jojo i'm 20 years old",
                 "my name is jojo i'm 20 years old and 6 miles away",
                 "blablabla 40% my name is jojo");
foreach ($strings as $string)
{
    preg_match_all("/([^0-9=%\s]\s?){10,}([0-9,.]+[^0-9=%]*){0,2}/", $string, $match);
    print_r($match[0]);
}
```

- `([^0-9=%\s]\s?){10,}` This matches at least 10 non-numerical-nor-`%=`-nor-space characters of which each may be followed by space.
- `([0-9,.]+[^0-9=%]*){0,2}` This matches at most 2 numbers of which each may be followed by other allowed characters.